# How can I call a function in ui.qml files in Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt-design-studio

I created a project in Qt Design Studio and then moved it to Qt Creator. I went through the conversion steps and now I only have .ui.qml files
Now I want call some functions in .ui.qml files. For example, I have a shape that I want to log a text by clicking on it. But qt creator alert me that I can not use functions or JavaScript blocks in Qt Quick UI forms.

errors in qt creator:

[image: errors in qt creator]

in `Main.ui.qml` :

```
import QtQuick 2.8

Item {
    id: main
    width: 1024
    height: 768
    
    Image {
        id: someImage
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                   // Here "JavaScript blocks are not supported in a Qt Quick UI 
                   // form." error occurs
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try with: `processor.menuClick(buttonText.titleText)`. Also provide a [mre]

Comment: the "processor" is an instance of custom c++ class in my code
the main problem is "Prohibition of writing function or js block in ui.qml files"

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: @eyllanesc no answer?